# How do I figure out what a WCF service is expecting?

Tags: wcf, node.js, soap

I am using Node.js and wcf.js module (npm install wcf.js)
The service i am trying to consume is https://webservice.kareo.com/services/soap/2.1/

I have figure out that this https://webservice.kareo.com/services/soap/2.1/KareoServices.svc?xsd=xsd0 contains what the service is looking to receive and that these https://webservice.kareo.com/services/soap/2.1/KareoServices.svc?wsdl=wsdl0 are the uri's to submit them to.

How in the world do i figure out how I am supposed to structure the request?
This is the example given to my by wcf.js

```
var BasicHttpBinding = require('wcf.js').BasicHttpBinding
  , Proxy = require('wcf.js').Proxy
  , binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
  , proxy = new Proxy(binding, " https://webservice.kareo.com/services/soap/2.1/")
  , message = '<Envelope xmlns=' +
            '"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                 '<Header />' +
                   '<Body>' +
                     '<GetData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">' +
                       '<value>GetAppointments</value>' +
                     '</GetData>' +
                    '</Body>' +
               '</Envelope>'

proxy.send(message, "http://www.kareo.com/api/schemas/KareoServices/GetAppointments", function(response, ctx) {
  console.log(response)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the wsdl this service uses BasicHttpBinding, which means no ws-secrutiy or addressing are used. In this case wcf.js does not bring you much added value on top of just using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) but nevertheless you can still use wcf.js. You need to set correctly 3 values - url, soapaction (the second param in the proxy ctor) and the soap. I recommend getting all 3 values by generating a c# client to this service, verifying the client works, and then setting up fiddler and pointing the client to "http://localhost:8888" so you will see in fiddler all 3 values and can configure them.

Comment: That worked great! fiddler put me in the right direction! Now is there a way to take the output into json? or parse it more cleanly?

like for(var i=0; o < response[Field].length; i++)

Comment: personally I think that if you work with xml it is better to stick to it and use xpath. if you prefer json use xml2js https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with wcf.js but, if you just need to see how you should structure you soap envelope to make a request I would suggest you fire up [wcftestclient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) and connect to the service. Once connected you can call any of the operations and view the soap message. Here is an empty request to the GetAppointments operation.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:Header>
        <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://www.kareo.com/api/schemas/KareoServices/GetAppointments</Action>
      </s:Header>
      <s:Body>
        <GetAppointments xmlns="http://www.kareo.com/api/schemas/">
          <request xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <RequestHeader i:nil="true" />
            <Fields i:nil="true" />
            <Filter i:nil="true" />
          </request>
        </GetAppointments>
      </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```